# Flutter build web Segmentation Fault - Failed to start event handler thread

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm encountering a segmentation fault error while running the flutter build web command as part of my CI pipeline. Here are the details of the error:

```
$ flutter build web --release --web-renderer=auto --dart-define develop=true
../../runtime/bin/eventhandler_linux.cc: 416: error: Failed to start event handler thread 1
===== CRASH =====
si_signo=Segmentation fault(11), si_code=1, si_addr=0x10
Aborting re-entrant request for stack trace.
/usr/bin/bash: line 126: 13 Aborted (core dumped) flutter build web --release --web-renderer=auto --dart-define develop=true
```

I'm not sure why this error is occurring, and I'd appreciate some guidance on how to resolve it. Here are some additional details:

I'm using Flutter version 3.10.6.
My operating system is MacOS.
I've tried running the command with different options, but the error persists.
I've searched for solutions online but haven't been able to find a clear resolution. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Flutter Web Should be build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are some miss configuration with your project. first try to `flutter clean` If its not working then try to upgrade flutter version using `flutter upgrade` and try to run it.

Comment: I have tried with Flutter clean but its not working let me try to upgrade the flutter version